# MYSQL Count Where Table is Crashed

Tags: mysql, crash

I am working with a very high traffic site where few mysql table is experiencing crash very frequently. I tried adding index and other but crash is happening. Now I am trying to auto repair  while its crashed. I can find the crash table with below query

```
show table status where comment like '%crash%'
```

And can make a repair with below query

```
REPAIR TABLE `mytable`;"
```

what my idea is to check crash table with a `count query` then if  `count>0`  then run the above repair table query. Is it possible to put above `show table status` query in a count function or there is another way

Comment: You probably can try using `information_schema.tables`. Here's a [reference](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/3222/191579)

Comment: You might also try asking about the crashes on [dba.se]. It's better that it doesn't crash in the first place.

Comment: *where few mysql table is experiencing crash very frequently* What is ENGINE of these tables?

Comment: Engine is MyISAM